# Making clang-format break after 'else'

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I prefer the following style:

```
if ( a )
  foo();
else // <- line break after else
if ( b )
  bar();
```

However, clang-format seems to always want to glue 'else if' together on the same line. Is there a way to achieve what I want with clang-format?

Comment: A quick look through https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html seems to indicate that this is not possible.

Comment: Btw your alignment is broken

Comment: Perhaps by putting a comment after every `else`, so that `clang-format` can't move the subsequent `if` to the same line?